# Чем отличаюстя последствия записи в несинхронизированную переменную?

Tags: c#, c++, c, .net, windows

Дана статическая переменная типа int (unsigned int в нативе), в которую из разных потоков пишутся (например инкремент) и читаются значения. Доступ к ней не синхронизирован.

Каковы последствия отсутствия синхронизации для натива (C\C++) и для управляемого кода (C#\VB .NET)?

p.s. насколько мне известно в управляемом коде будет только потеря точности (из-за возможной несвоевременной перезаписи значения переменной), а в нативе будет падение приложения?

Comment: Если адреса переменной выровнен, ни потерь точности ни падений, не будет. Но будут другие проблемы. Безопаснее всего(но не быстрее) защитить переменую interlock функциями.

Comment: В нативе будет неопределенное поведение.

Comment: В нативе ничего не упадет, но разные потоки могут видеть разное значение (пока кеш линия на процессоре не синхронизируется).

Comment: @VTT, можете рассказать подробнее про УБ из-за чего именно оно возникнет?

Comment: @goldstar_labs Это задано в стандарте, в разделе с описанием многопоточного поведения: **4.7.1 Data races [intro.races]** *"20 ... The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two potentially concurrent conflicting actions,
at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other, except for the special case for signal handlers described below. Any such data race results in undefined behavior."*